# Git Folder Looks gray at github repository

Tags: github

[image]

I got two folders in that repository Server and vacation, and everytime I'm pushing vacation it does'nt really push it. From what I undestood this is a "submodule" folder. I have been trying  type `git rm --cached vacation`
but it still keep upload the folder like you can see above...
What can I do to make git push this folder like it pushed server?

When I'm typing `git remote -v` in vacation folder this are the branches it shows:[image]

Comment: The folder icon next to vacation says that the folder is empty.

Comment: Why would it say that?

Comment: Because the folder is empty? xD

Comment: It ain't empty it's full of react garbage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git does not save empty folders. if you add just any file it will be in the folder you put it but empty folders doesn't saved, because git was invented to work on files